# Create table in Excel 2010 With Underscore instead of spaces along with a named range

Tags: vb.net, ado.net, oledb

I am using Visual Studio 2010 Professional with Excel 2010. The following code creates a table Called "Hourly_Burn_Data_By_Plant" instead of "Hourly Burn Data By Plant" and a named range with the same name On the field row of the new table. This creates errors when adding data to the table. What am doing wrong?

```
    Dim ConStrTemp As String
    ConStrTemp = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & "C:\Studies\NewHourlyFuel\Book1.xlsx" & _
    ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;"""        'Mode=ReadWrite;ReadOnly=False;"""

    Dim ConnTemp As New OleDbConnection(ConStrTemp)
    Globals.OpenConn(ConnTemp)
    Dim ExistingTables() As String
    ExistingTables = Globals.GetTableNamesFromConn(ConnTemp)
    Dim i As Int16
    For i = 0 To ExistingTables.GetUpperBound(0)
        Debug.Print(ExistingTables(i))
    Next
    Dim NametoCreate As String = "Hourly Burn Data By Plant"

    Dim CreateSQL As String = "Create Table [" & NametoCreate & "] ([Plant] char(50), [RDate] Date, [Period 1] float, " & _
        "[Period 2] float, [Period 3] float, [Period 4] float, [Period 5] float, [Period 6] float, [Period 7] float, [Period 8] float, [Period 9] float, " & _
        "[Period 10] float, [Period 11] float, [Period 12] float, [Period 13] float, [Period 14] float, [Period 15] float, [Period 16] float, [Period 17] float, " & _
        "[Period 18] float, [Period 19] float, [Period 20] float, [Period 21] float, [Period 22] float, [Period 23] float, [Period 24] float, [Daily Total] float)"

    Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(CreateSQL, ConnTemp)
    Try
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MsgBox("susccess")
        ExistingTables = Globals.GetTableNamesFromConn(ConnTemp)
        For i = 0 To ExistingTables.GetUpperBound(0)
            Debug.Print(ExistingTables(i))
        Next
        Globals.CloseConn(ConnTemp)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Failure " & ex.Message)
        Globals.CloseConn(ConnTemp)
    End Try
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct create table syntax in excel would be:

```
CREATE TABLE `SheetName`  (`ColumnName1` TYPE, `ColumnName2` TYPE)
```

Where TYPE = see link below

http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/acpcref/63184/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a003072672.htm

Note the use of ` and not [] as name identifiers...

Comment: I treid the following:  CreateSQL = "Create Table " & "'" & NametoCreate & "'" & " (Section Char(50), RDAte Date, " & "'" & "Period 1" & "'" & " Float)" and I get "Syntax error in create SQL" message.